# Symfony + Twig + Semantic UI = Background image doesn't show up

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig, background-image

could anyone please help me with understanding what is going wrong in my code? I use Symfony 2.8, Semantic UI and Twig and trying to simply put a picture in background of my site. I'm modifying my base.html.twig file to do that.

I tried to:

1. use different pictures in different formats and sizes
2. place picture in different locations:

   - in app/Resources/views
   - in src/AppBundle/Resources/public/images
   - in web/semantic - that's where I keep Semantic UI files
3. use different ways of setting up:

   - as body tag attribute
   - as inline style placed in body tag
   - as internal style used in div tag
   - as external style - I modified Semantic UI css

I checked if it's not a problem with path name with sereval experiment's. It's not. What's important: when I tried to simply set background color, each time it worked well. Only pictures does't show up.

Any suggestions how to solve that problem?

This is my base.html.twig file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{% block title %} Address Book {% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('/semantic/semantic.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="{{ asset('/semantic/semantic.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(siano.jpg)">
    <div class="ui center aligned container">
        <div class="ui grid">
            <div class="four wide column"></div>
            <div class="eight wide column">
                <p>
                    <h1> Address Book </h1><br>
                </p>
                {% block body %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="four wide column"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

In situation above files structure is:

```
AppBundle
    Resources
        views
            base.html.twig
            siano.jpg
```

Comment: Can you teach me how to adopt `Semantic-ui` to `Symfony` framework?
I have no idea about it to approach the `Webpack` tool usage, and `semantic-ui` also not support `yarn` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Move your image to web/images.

And then:

```
<body style="background-image:url('{{ asset('images/siano.jpg') }}')">
<div class="ui center aligned container">
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
        <div class="eight wide column">
            <p>
                <h1> Address Book </h1><br>
            </p>
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! It worked. What a relief :) But that brings another question: I used  app/console assest:install web --symlink to corelate my image files in bundle with web directory. It created path: web > bundles > app > images > siano.jpg and this connection (as we know now) doesn't work. Should I rather stick to your suggestion and create web > images on my own each time instead?